# Incarceration Math Book Recommendation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

My 35 year old son is in jail for a few months and he asked me to send him a book (or books) that he could use to review math from Algebra through Calculus.  He has no internet so needs a great text or two. He likes math but it has been about 10 years since he last studied it in college.  He needs something with excellent explanations and examples, and hopefully one with an answer key showing all steps. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Calculus by stewart

Comment: Paul Foerster's algebra books [Algebra I](https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-1-Expressions-Equations-Applications/dp/020132458X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1543581933&sr=8-2&keywords=paul+foerster) and [Algebra and Trigonometry](https://www.amazon.com/Algebra-Trigonometry-Functions-Applications-Prentice/dp/0131657100/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1543581933&sr=8-1&keywords=paul+foerster) are useful, as is the text [Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Ray-C-Jurgensen/dp/0395977274/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1543582373&sr=1-1&keywords=jurgensen+geometry) by Jurgensen, Brown, and Jurgensen.

Comment: Thank you so much for these recommendations!  I So appreciate your help.